# Is Inkscape meant to look like Windows XP on 19.04?

Tags: themes, 19.04, interface, inkscape

When I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, Inkscape suddenly looked like this:
[image: this]
which isn't how it looked before.

If it isn't meant to look like that, any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: That was not a really good idea to upgrade from an LTS to a non-LTS release. Some GTK libraries didn't install.

Comment: Is inkscape installed as a snap? Check with `snap list`.

Comment: snap is unlikely. It would contain all libs.

Comment: @mook765 It isn't there.

Comment: @Pilot6 What should I do? Just re-install Inkscape?

Comment: That won't help. I saw a  Q&A with a similar problem. Installing of some gnome gtk packages solved it. But that was about some libreoffice program. You can install a snap. That should fix it.

Comment: Is this happening *only* with Inkscape?

Comment: @pomsky Currently, I haven't noticed it elsewhere. But initially, Rhythmbox looked like that as well, however, after a few reboots it sorted itself out.

Comment: @Chlodio Only Rhythmbox sorted itself out, or Inkscape too?

Comment: @pomsky Only Rhythmbox box.